# Microsoft video and audio recording utility has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, mstest, video-recording, microsoft-test-manager

I have a bunch of automated running test on a hyper-v environment. I want to record my screen as the tests are running. If the tests are runned by the night build I don't have video recorded for the tests which are red and I see on the machine a window with the following error: "Microsoft video and audio recording utility has stopped working". If I start the tests again and connect to the machine to see how they are running automatically the video recording does work and I have a video for the red tests. The user is the same that I set for the test agent and with who I am connecting to the hyper-v machine. So the video recording is working for me just if I am logged on on the machine.

Three Errors are in the Event Log:

1 Application Error:

Faulting application name: VSTestVideoRecorder.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time stamp: 0x5011e088
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18247, time stamp: 0x521ea8e7
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x000325c1
Faulting process id: 0xfb0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf423e2744987b
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors\VSTestVideoRecorder.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 0ca02861-ae32-11e3-aaba-00155d706101

2 VSTTAgentProcess

(QTDCAgent32.exe, PID 680, Thread 24) DataCollectionEvents: Timed out invoking target 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder.VideoRecorderDataCollector' event handler 'OnTestCaseEnd' with event args 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution.TestCaseEndEventArgs'

3 VSTTAgentProcess

(QTDCAgent32.exe, PID 680, Thread 24) Data collector 'datacollector://microsoft/VideoRecorder/1.0' logged the following error: The adapter 'Video Recorder' will not be used for this test run.  The adapter did not respond to the event in 300 seconds.

To increase the timeout values for all diagnostic data adapters, see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237103&clcid=0x409

Comment: Did you check the event log?

Comment: Yes, I added it to my post.

Comment: Have you already tried to increase the timeout value? If it does not help I would suggest to post your question to the [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home)

Comment: Hi, I will try it on Friday. Thanks.